# Oracle adf 12c Load more scroll new policy

Tags: oracle-adf

hi I've added the new scroll load more policy onto my table grid and it works just fine. But after i have deleted a column from the grid it doesn't show the load more scroll anymore, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

> But after i have deleted a column from the grid

Probably you have deleted more than necessary.
If you use a version control, you should revert to your previous state (before removing), make sure code works and remove the column again.

You should always compare the changes you made against the one from version control, to be sure you change only what you are supposed to.

Learning using version control is an important element ADF study.

Comment: the column i'm talking about was deleted at runtime, there is nothing i did to the code, More like deleting a row of data on the grid.

Comment: In this case, you better fill a SR with Oracle